# Powershell wait for dotnet run to launch application on some port

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script that is supposed to run two dotnet application one after the other. One on port 5000 the second one on port 5001 according to their launchSettings.json

So far this is the script that runs the applications:

```
    $app1ProjectFolder = '../src/App1'
    $app2ProjectFolder = '../src/App2'

    Write-Host "STARTING APP1" -foreground Green

    Push-Location $app1ProjectFolder 

    $dotnetRunCommandApp1 = 'run'
    $app1Process = Start-Process dotnet -ArgumentList $dotnetRunCommandApp1 -PassThru

    Pop-Location

    Write-Host "STARTING APP2" -foreground Green

    Push-Location $app2ProjectFolder 

    $dotnetRunCommandApp2 = 'run'
    $app2Process = Start-Process dotnet -ArgumentList $dotnetRunCommandApp2 -PassThru

    Pop-Location
```

What I need is for the script to wait for the first app to finish launching or be accessible on it's designated port before launching the second app.

Comment: You could use a `do{} while()` loop to run `netstat -an`, store that in a variable, then parse the results for the computer name and port, and a state of ESTABLISHED. Then your loop can run indefinitely until that application is up and running, then continue with your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
while (!(Test-NetConnection localhost -Port 5000).TcpTestSucceeded) { Start-Sleep 1 }
```

To wait indefinitely for the ports to be ready.

You could add a maximum wait time e.g. say the app stayed running but failed to listen, or was firewalled.

Answer (score 1):

Start-Process has the -wait switch which should prevent the script from continuing until it's done.

`$app1Process = Start-Process dotnet -ArgumentList $dotnetRunCommandApp1 -PassThru -wait`

According to the [Start-Process article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-6#parameters):

> Indicates that this cmdlet waits for the specified process and its descendants to complete before accepting more input. This parameter suppresses the command prompt or retains the window until the processes finish.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong... but `dotnet run` process won't complete after the application has been launched... I need the first application to be launched and keep running when starting up the second application

Comment: Ah, you're right, I didn't read through it carefully enough. This probably would just get stuck waiting forever.