# Batch File: Wait until multiple dotnet run commands are finished before launching browser shortcut

Tags: asp.net, .net, batch-file, .net-core

I have a batch file that executes:

`start cmd /k dotnet run -p projectName`

For two separate projects and then launches a shortcut link to the angular project in browser. The only (semi) problem is that the shortcut launches before the dotnet run commands have finished and so the browser believes the site cannot be reached until the dotnet run commands are complete.

I'm trying to not launch the shortcut link **until** both projects have finished executing the dotnet run command so the "This site can't be reached" dialog never shows up. I don't personally mind it, but it's rather confusing to anyone thinking the application should just open without the need for a reload.

EDIT:

The projects I'm running are a .NET Core Web API & .NET Core (Angular) Web App. The angular app get's compiled and served via dotnet run, but both projects need to remain running in order to listen to their specific ports. And the shortcut link executed at the end of the batch file is just to open the browser at localhost:AngularPort#. I understand a desktop app would have probably been the way to go from the start but for v2, the plan is to host in azure and allow customers to access the site as well instead of just being an internal app.

Comment: `start/wait "" cmd /c dotnet` in place of `start cmd /k dotnet` perhaps?

Comment: `Cmd1 && cmd2` syntax makes that cmd2 is executed after cmd1 has finished (correctly).

Comment: `dotnet run -p projectName`.

Comment: @Magoo Unfortunately the wait argument waits until the project is shut down instead of when it's served to localhost and I need both projects (api & angular) to remain running. Thanks for the reply though :D

Comment: @MicEsp I'm unfamiliar with the && syntax but I'm pretty new to batch files. It sounds promising though so I'm going to look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Just `start dotnet run -p projectname` then. A programs status is set when it exits.

Comment: @user14797724 I'm unclear on if you mean exits the cmd or the line of code, however the projects need to both remain running in order for the browser to get into the angular app and access the local api. On top of that the batch file can't execute any commands after dotnet run unless either it's executed in a new cmd window, or the project itself get's shut down. I'm assuming because dotnet run is still considered executing while it's listening on it's ports.

Comment: Type `start/?` for help on starting programs. Also see `call /?`, `cmd /?` and `timeout /?`.

Comment: Okay, so you want to run two parallel process and wait for those process to start and get far enough into their execution, that a third parallel process can communicate with the first two, yes/no?

Comment: @jwdonahue exactly, but the more I think about it. It seems unlikely that there is any hook into a (sort of) arbitrary point in the dotnet run command that's not technically when it completes.

Comment: @jwdonahue Before I posted the question I tried this to wait until the port number was ready but it didn't work. Here's a link to the solution I tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134434/powershell-wait-for-dotnet-run-to-launch-application-on-some-port

Comment: GUI programs have https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-waitforinputidle.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on npm with a package called 'wait-on' which in my case will wait until an http(s) request on that url returns a response with a status code in the 200 range before completing. There's a whole other assortment of use-cases with this package but I only needed it for that.

Here's a link to the package if anyone else runs into this problem:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-on

Edit:

Honestly this was only a problem because the laptop I needed to put the application on didn't have the best CPU stats, so it got hung up trying to serve a local api and angular application simultaneously.